# Specify shape for categorical feature columns?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

I know that I can use a [`categorical_column_with_identity`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/feature_column/categorical_column_with_identity) to turn a categorical feature into a series of one-hot features.

For instance, if my vocabulary is `["ON", "OFF", "UNKNOWN"]`:
`"OFF"` -> `[0, 1, 0]`

```
categorical_column = tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_identity('column_name', num_buckets=3)
feature_column = tf.feature_column.indicator_column(categorical_column))
```

---

However, I actually have an 1-dimensional array of categorical features. I would like to turn that into a 2-dimensional series of one-hot features:

`["OFF", "ON", "OFF", "UNKNOWN", "ON"]`
->
`[[0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0]]`

Unlike every other feature column, it doesn't seem like there's a `shape` attribute on `categorical_column_with_identity` and I didn't find any help through Google or the docs.

Do I have to give up on `categorical_column_with_identity` and create the 2D array myself through a `numerical_column`?

Comment: I have no experience whatsoever with `tesorflow`. But I know this is possible by other means, e.g. `pandas` library. Are you open to other methods?

Comment: Yep, if I can't find a way to conveniently do directly with the tensorflow column, I'll just have to do it using pandas. Feel free to post your answer.
It just seems strange to me that this isn't a common use case, especially since every other type of column has some kind of "shape" argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the comments, I'm not sure this functionality is possible with `tensorflow`. But with Pandas you have a trivial solution via [`pd.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html):

```
import pandas as pd

L = ['OFF', 'ON', 'OFF', 'UNKNOWN', 'ON']

res = pd.get_dummies(L)

print(res)

   OFF  ON  UNKNOWN
0    1   0        0
1    0   1        0
2    1   0        0
3    0   0        1
4    0   1        0
```

For performance, or if you need only a NumPy array, you can use [`LabelBinarizer`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelBinarizer.html) from `sklearn.preprocessing`:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer

LB = LabelBinarizer()

res = LB.fit_transform(L)

print(res)

array([[1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0]])
```

Answer (score 2):

A couple options for binary encoding

```
import tensorflow as tf
test = ["OFF", "ON", "OFF", "UNKNOWN", "ON"]
encoding = {x:idx for idx, x in enumerate(sorted(set(test)))}
test = [encoding[x] for x in test]
print(tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(test, num_classes=len(encoding)))

>>>[[1. 0. 0.]
    [0. 1. 0.]
    [1. 0. 0.]
    [0. 0. 1.]
    [0. 1. 0.]]
```

Or from scikit as the other answer stated

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer
encoder = LabelBinarizer()
transfomed_label = encoder.fit_transform(["OFF", "ON", "OFF", "UNKNOWN", "ON"])
print(transfomed_label)

>>>[[1 0 0]
    [0 1 0]
    [1 0 0]
    [0 0 1]
    [0 1 0]]
```

Comment: Just a note, *if* Pandas is permitted you can avoid the dict and list comprehensions via `pd.factorize(test, sort=True)[0]`. In my opinion, given the end product is an array it *may* be idiomatic to get the array conversion done early on.

Comment: I wasn't aware of `tf.keras.utils.to_categorical`, that's pretty convenient, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dict as a map like this:

```
categorical_features = ["OFF", "ON", "OFF", "UNKNOWN", "ON"]
one_hot_features = []

map = {"ON": [1, 0, 0], "OFF": [0, 1, 0], "UNKNOWN": [0, 0, 1]}

for val in categorical_features:
    one_hot_features.append(map[val])
```

or with list comprehension:
    categorical_features = ["OFF", "ON", "OFF", "UNKNOWN", "ON"]

```
map = {"ON": [1, 0, 0], "OFF": [0, 1, 0], "UNKNOWN": [0, 0, 1]}
one_hot_features = [map[f] for f in categorical_features]
```

This should give you what you want.